# Simulate a select and submit form with jQuery without a select

Tags: php, jquery, html

To avoid using a jQuery plugin to stylize a `select`, I created a custom solution with HTML & CSS *but* with a hidden `select` and a form.

When I click on a link of the *fake select*, it select the same option value in the *real select* and I submit the form.

Do you have an idea to avoid this behavior and "remove" the `select` ?
Is there possible to have just a form and to submit informations like the true `select` only with jQuery ?

### HTML & PHP

```
<div class="sorter">
    <span class="legend">Sort by</span>
    <form method="post" class="sort">

        <?php
            $orderby = array(
                "date" => "Year",
                "director" => "Director",
                "production" => "Production"
            );
        ?>

        <a href="#" id="order_result"><?= (!empty($_POST["select"])) ? $orderby[$_POST["select"]] : "Year" ?></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-sort="date">Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-sort="director">Director</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-sort="production">Production</a></li>
        </ul>

        <select name="select" id="orderby">
            <?php foreach ($orderby as $k => $v) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $k ?>" <?php selected($_POST["select"], $k, 1) ?>><?= $v ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".sorter a").on("click", function(e){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#order_result").text(text);
    $(this).closest("form").find($("select option[value=" + $(this).data('sort') + "")).prop("selected", true);
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: _"but with a hidden select and a form."_ - Why don't you use an `<input type="hidden">` field and set its value directly from the clicked item in your pseudo-select?

Comment: why not use a plugin? You should always remember that there are people who have javascript disabled. So a good plugin works fully unobtrusive, so if you've disabled javascript you see the normal select list.

Comment: I don't have a submit button and I need to use javascript to submit the form, so…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with a hidden input (thanks @nnnnnn, I don't use them often…) works well !

```
<form method="post" class="sort">
    <input type="hidden" name="sortby" id="sortby">
    <?php
        $orderby = array(
            "date" => "Année",
            "director" => "Réalisateur",
            "production" => "Production"
        );
    ?>
    <a href="#" id="order_result"><?= (!empty($_POST["sortby"])) ? $orderby[$_POST["sortby"]] : "Année" ?></a>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($orderby as $k => $v) : ?>
        <li><a href="#" data-sort="<?= $k ?>"><?= $v ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

-

```
$(".sorter a").on("click", function(e){
    $("#order_result").text($(this).text());
    $(this).closest("form").find("#sortby").val($(this).data("sort"));
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a `ul` list dynamically from `select` list, then create a `hidden input` and remove the `select` list?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var select  = $("select#orderby").hide(0);
    var ul      = $("<ul />").insertBefore( select );
    var input   = $("<input />",{"type":"hidden","name":select.attr("name"),"value":select.val()}).insertAfter( ul );

    $("option",select).each(function() {
      var val = $(this).val();
      var txt = $(this).text();
      var li  = $("<li />").appendTo( ul ),
          a   = $("<a />",{"href":"#"}).on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            input.val( val );
            //select.val( val );
            $(this).parents("form:first").trigger("submit");
          }).html( txt ).appendTo( li );
    });

    select.remove();
  });
</script>
```